# Regex for two digit number followed by . for find and replace in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I want to find out following string pattern in `vim` and replace it with some thing else. Can you please tell me `regex` for the same.

```
 1.
11.
20.
21.
99.
```

basically one / two digits followed by dot.

Comment: Without at least a basic understanding of regular expressions, you won't get much out of Vim. Seriously, start learning, either from tutorials on the net, or Vim's built-in `:help`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you could do something like the following (I'm not very experienced with VI so there might be a better way)

```
:%s/\d\+\./MyString/gc
```

So that's essentially using `\d\+\.` to search for numbers appearing one or more times followed by a `.`.

`MyString` is your replacement string.

`:%s` is the substitute command, `:s` would just search the current line.

`/gc` looks for the match as many times as it appears on the line (`g`), and asks for confirmation before each replacement (`c`).

Comment: if you need to choose some number seq, then you can simply use {times}:
123
234
123456

:%s/\d\{3}/MyString/g <- will replace all matches with 3 digits
:%s/\d\{6}//g <- will delete all matches with 6 digits

Answer (score 1):

Tried this?

```
[^0-9][0-9][0-9]\.
```

Or have you tried it and it didn't work?

It has an issue though of three digits and a dot, i.e. "123." will also be captured

Comment: I tried after you answered and it is not working.

Comment: I tried find and replace in gvim using [^0-9][0-9][0-9]\. it says pattern not found.

Comment: @nrathaus: He didn't use code tags and appeared all its numbers in the same line but they are different. I've edited his questions but now in your answer the current `[^0-9]` avoids the match.

Comment: originally you wanted two digits and a dot, now its one or more digits and a dot, so my [^0-9] was there to avoid the case of three digits, and also to make sure that there are at least two

Answer (score 1):

The regex for 1 or 2 digits followed by a dot is:

```
\<\d\d\?\.
```

The "word boundary" `\<` precludes 3 digits (and a dot), which would be allowed without it (the last two digits of a 3-digit number would match).

To replace using this tegex in vi:

```
s/\<\d\d\?\./foo/g
```

Comment: No, in Vim `\b` is not the word boundary, it's backspace. `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries. And `?` is written `\=` (or `\?`) in Vim.

Comment: @glts thx. been a while since I've touched vi. Didn't realise it was so different